# MOSFET gate drivers

Tags: mosfet, resonance, powermosfet

This circuit requires two gate drivers to drive a push-pull configuration, can anyone recommend any since the source of the top MOSFET is floating it isnt as simple as a low-side driver. They would replace the NOT gates. The series LC circuit provides feedback for the oscillations.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: My recommendation is that you turn Q1 round so the body diode doesn't conduct all the time.

Comment: This is a shopping question. It is possible to buy an integrated driver that has high side and low side drivers integrated in one package. I think it would be called a half-bridge driver. The high side driver would probably use the bootstrap method to generate a voltage high enough to turn on the high-side FET. This means that there would be duty-cycle limitations. You wouldn't be able to just turn the high-side FET on at 100% duty cycle. Often this is perfectly OK.

Comment: Note that most half-bridge drivers are for two NMOS transistors. Driving 1 PMOS and one NMOS is different, and this schematic has more than one problem doing that. Apart from Q1's orientation, there's a problem with the polarity of its gate drive!

Comment: Yeah what Brian said. I may have seen one or two designed for PMOS on the high side. Not sure. But the majority will be N-channel on the high side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, you are using Q1 in the wrong way, so you should flip it, reverse biasing it body diode when it is off.

Second point, if you want to use a P-channel mosfet in the High side of a half-bridge, you should not care about the floating voltage of the output node, as it source should be connected to the VDD node, so a constant voltage.

In addition, it is not the purpose of this forum to recommend any specific part number, because it will become obsolete sometime, so this topic could be not helpful to someone else in the future.

Finally, you should be aware of the fact that you can implement a halfbridge also with a NMOS in the high side. For a couple of reasons (faster switching, lower ON resistance and others) this type of implementation is more efficient. Therefore, great part of mosfet's gate drivers are designed to be used with two N-MOSFETs forming the halfbrige. If you want to use a PMOS in the high side, search for "PMOS-NMOS bridge driver" or something similar to find your part.

If you want to move your design to a double N channel halfbrige, you will need to use a driver that uses some special technique, like bootstrap. This app note is a good reference to learn about it: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-6076.pdf